# could someone explain me this matlab code?

Tags: matlab, binary, image

What does the following MATLAB code do?

```
binaryImage = zeros(size(Image));
binaryImage(106<=Image(:)&Image(:)<=169) = 1;
```

Comment: This could probably be done more succinctly with `binaryImage = double(106 <= Image & Image <= 169)`.

Answer (score 5):

In the first statement the `binaryImage` variable is set to a matrix of zeros of the same size as the matrix `Image`. The second statement sets all elements of the `binaryImage` matrix to one where the corresponding element in the `Image` matrix is between 106 and 169.